# Custom shaped droppable zones?

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg

I have a three point line, I would like to separate the court in sections so that when an object is dropped it is set inside either close, mid-range or three point.

I am not sure how to do this since the lines are curved. I looked into svg and canvas not sure if those are what I need.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When your object is dropped, you can get the x/y drop-point from the ui object:**

```
$('#basketballCourt').droppable( {

    drop: function(event, ui){
        var dropY=ui.position.top;
        var dropX=ui.position.left;
    }

});
```

**Then you can use an offscreen html canvas to test where that drop-point is within your court.**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/a4gUH/

[image]  [image] [image]

In particular, `context.isPointInPath(dropX,dropY)` can be used to test if the drop-point is within your "inside", "2-point" or "3-point" drop zones.

How it works:

- Create an offscreen canvas the same size as your image.
- Define 3 drop-paths (one for each of your drop-zones).
- When the use drops, test which drop-path the drop-point is within using context.isPointInPath.

This is code to test if the drop-point is within the "inside" drop zone:

```
function isInside(x,y){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(76,190,125,90);
    return(ctx.isPointInPath(x,y));
}
```

This is code to test if the drop-point is within the "2-point" drop zone:

```
function is2Point(x,y){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(76,125);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(300,120,300,355,76,350);
    ctx.closePath();
    return(ctx.isPointInPath(x,y));
}
```

If the drop-point is not within either "inside" or "2-point", then it's within "3-point"

Comment: Wow just logged in this looks cool, let me get into it :) I just want to give you a green check now, the fiddle looks awesome. Let me get the code in my head first.

Comment: Wow you're the best, I am really excited about all this cool technology that is being created, html5 rocks.

Comment: I know this is marked complete, but could you explain how you created the bezierCurveTo? and got the exact x y coordinates? In the real image I need to adjust the position and I am just guessing, I am wondering what process you used?

Comment: I know Bez-curves are difficult to mentally internalize.  I got experience with Bez-curves using Photoshop.  There are 4 points that define the curve. Points 1 & 4 are easy--they are just the beginning and ending points of your curve.  Here's a mental trick to positioning points 2 & 3.  Think of point 2 as a magnet that attracts the curve coming out of point 1.  And point 3 attracts the curve coming out of point 4. This online playground might help you get experience to mentally internalize the Bez-curve: http://cs.jsu.edu/~leathrum/gwtmathlets/mathlets.php?name=bezier

Comment: Here's a "playground" to help you internalize how Bezier curves are formed.  If you need, you can download the code and replace the image with another.  Cheers! http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aWLQx/

Comment: Thanks that helps, been a long day lol I finally got the code to work in my app, see I had a foreach loop. I just wraped the code in a var function then set the canvas object to be the active canvas by firing it every time a new active state takes place. I have yet to incorporate `draggable`, I hope I get that working soon. You've been a great help setting me in the right direction. This helped me with the bezier http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_beziercurveto Hope to get this functional today :)

Comment: hey I am going to open a new question about connecting draggable with the canvas, I am a little confused, I can award you the answer. Would you be willing to help?